# Can i use I2C level shifters to power digital LED strips

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, led-strip, ws2812b

Can I use I2C level shifters to power digital LED strips, more specifically, WS2812B strips?

I can only find I²C level shifters, are they ok?

Comment: I believe you mean 'I2C'?

Comment: @ChrisFernandez, yes I do

Comment: Well hit the edit link under your question and fix it. Welcome to EE.SE!

Comment: What voltage levels are you interfacing and from what part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use I²C level shifters to drive WS2812B Digital LED strips?

Your question could do to be clarified somewhat.

I assume that you want to interface a 3.3V MCU controller to the 5V required for the WS2812 LED strips data input.

The readily available level shifters use a single active device and are very suitable for your task.

I assume you are using something like this:
[image]

This is the typical schematic for the level shifter:

[image]

These will work well for your application.
Connect LV to 3.3V, and drive the TX2_LV from your 3.3V MCU.
Connect HV to 5V, and drive the WS2812B data pin from TX2_HV.

The cost of these level shifter (10 for less than $3) makes them ideal for the hobbyist. One level shifter board will drive 4 individual LED strips.

Note: After active discussion in the comments I'll add this:

1. It may be worthwhile to put a resistor (I'd recommend no less than 1k Ohm)  in parallel with the 10k pullup on the level translator.
2. Some recommend a series resistor in the Din line ….but from my experience all the WS2812B based LED strips already have a 33 Ohm in series with Din. In my view that is enough. Some comments on this series resistor advise it because the first pixel can be damaged by high voltage. The only way I can conceive of this happening is if the LED strip is unpowered and the MCU is powered. In this case the pullup resistor for the level shifter already acts as a series resistor, so IMO no addition series resistor is required.
   Using a series resistor for the push-pull level translators (positioned at the translator and before the TP cable actually introduces extra risetime and I don't recommend any more than 150 Ohm.
3. Most of the strips I've bought are WS2812B based ….eventually they will all be WS2812B-V4 based. The Din pin on this unit is 12V proof so any of the fixes for the WS2812B will no longer apply. The -V4 is supposedly 3.3V compliant, so the need for level translation will I assume vanish with time.
4. If you are driving LED strips far from the controller then you have more to worry about. If the strips are powered from different power supplies or if there is voltage drop in the ground wires this is best fixed with optical isolation of Din. I've used two opto-couplers and an SR flip-flop to provide long runs (both for PWM and Data driven LED strips.

From the comments these two links provide useful commentary (particularly the comments):

- https://happyinmotion.com/?p=1247
- http://www.electrobob.com/ws2812-level-translator/

Comment: *Maybe*.  The 10K pullup resistor may be marginal for the data rates that WS2812's are *intended* to run at.  A bidirectional IC driver is really preferable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You are driving a single input on the WS2812 LED strip …..there would be zero problem with the 10k pullup out to several meters. You could drop the resistor if the line length was long of course.

Comment: ANy communication channel design needs much better specs in the question to give a guaranteed solution in any answer. bit rate, cable type, grounding., length, Voltage impedance. stray noise PSU CM noise, Why guess on a level shifter and R that might be a waste of time?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Since we don't know the length of the (hopefully) twisted pair going from the MCU to the LED strip it's hard to say. The level shifter is still a more than viable choice to drive the TP since you could reduce the pullup resistor to 220 Ohms if required. You certainly don't need to drive it at the characteristic impedance of the TP at these data rates. There will not be enough CM noise to impact this sort of application. The vast majority of DIY build have the power supply and controller no more than a few meters from the strips. Don't over engineer.

Comment: Never assume.....unless clear about assumptions

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Then lets just wait for the OP to comment. In the meantime I stand by my comments ….the OP won't have any problems if the controller and strip are separated by only a few meters.

Comment: FYI - https://happyinmotion.com/?p=1247

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It was the simplest, and since I am very new to this sort of stuff, it was what I was looking for. I was kind of nervous because I²C level shifters were the only ones I could find, and I read somewhere that they were not good to use for LED strips.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Great post, some excellent comments in the link you provided. The other document worth reading is the Adafruit Uberguide: https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide.pdf

Comment: @SakerAlabas no, this is not the simplest, and it is **the wrong tool for the job** with a very real chance of not working.  A push-pull IC driver as in Spehro's properly *engineered* answer will be both simpler and cheaper.

Answer (score 5):

I2C is bidirectional, you don't need bidirectional level shifters for the WS2812B which uses a single-wire asynchronous protocol.

For example, [74LVCH1T45](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC_LVCH1T45.pdf) is a suitable unidirectional level shifter that will work with a wide range of input and output voltages.

Edit: Bidirectional level shifters with discrete MOSFETs that use 10K pullups will likely cause problems- the tolerance is +/-150ns on the timing. A time constant of 150ns with 10K is the equivalent of only a few inches of wire. It will probably work with a very short wire, but become erratic or stop working with longer lengths. If you mount the level shifter right beside the first WS2812B in the chain it may be usable.

Timing requirements from the [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf):

[image]

Here is a simulation of the BSS138 circuit. The red represents the minimum the WS2812B requires (timing and Vih). With a load of only 5pF and all voltages at nominal the timing is barely meeting spec typically. In any real setup this will be **guaranteed** to be out of spec, and if it works it will be by luck.

[image]

When estimating we cannot ignore the input capacitance of the WS2812B nor the significant capacitance of the BSS138 (although it's one of the lowest capacitance types that is suitable).

Of course you can, most likely, reduce the output 10K resistor or parallel it with another resistor and get it to work reliably enough for a hobby project.

Comment: I disagree. A 10k pullup is more than adequate to drive several meters of twisted pair and meet all the timing requirements. For example it adequately supports I2C at 1Mbps out to several meters.   ...Though I have to agree with you that the 74LVCH1T45 is a good solution if you are designing you own PCB.

Comment: Given a twisted cable of 50 to 100pF/m or 0.5 to 1us/m risetime several meters will limit the BW to well below 1Mbps with 10k  pullup would have to be reduced. and push-pull CMOS direct with suitable <0.3 to >0.7*Vdd should be best for simplex data @JackCreasey FWIW  then add 22R as required

Comment: as the 74LVC family is Vol/Iol= 550mV/32mA @ 4.5V =17 ohm typ.

Comment: @JackCreasey They won't come close to meeting specification (has to be 400ns +/-150ns over Vil = 0.7 Vdd)  even with the 15pF input capacitance load on the 400ns pulse width and perfect input waveform. Do a simulation if you don't believe me.  The bandwidth has to be much higher than 1MHz to meet spec even with no noise margin.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Lets consider a TP from an Ethernet cable (https://files.cablewholesale.com/pdfspecs/11x8-0xxth.pdf) since that's what I normally use. 330pf/100meter ….5m is about 16pf …..RC (http://referencedesigner.com/rfcal/cal_05.php) 10k * 16pf is about 160ns ….so we could consider this about the maximum distance with a 10k pullup ….reduce the distance to 4m and you are solidly able to meet the spec. And I said in my comments you could use a few meters …….I consider 4m a few meters.

Comment: @JackCreasey See simulation. We can't ignore the MOSFET output capacitance nor the input capacitance.

Comment: FYI: https://happyinmotion.com/?p=1247